# SQL query through JDBC connection slower depending on where the DataSource object is accessed

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm working on a project which utilizes the Service Locator pattern, and also has a static class which contains the DataSource object that we use to do all of our database transactions. The general setup looks like the following code snippets:

```
public class Environment {
    //multiple app instances on one server
    private static final HashMap<String, DataSource> appDatasources = new HashMap<>();

    public static DataSource getDataSource(String appName){
        return appDatasources.get(appName);
    }
    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return appDatasources.get(getApplicationName());
    }
    public static String getApplicationName(){
        return ServiceLocator.getAppName();
    }

    public static void createDatasource(String jdbc, String appName){
        org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriveClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        ds.setUrl(jdbc);
        ds.setMaxActive(100);
        ds.setMaxIdle(50);
        ds.setInitialSize(10);
        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);
        ds.setLogAbandoned(true);

        appDatasources.put(appName, ds);
    }
}

}
public class ServiceLocatorFactory(String appName) {

    public static void registerServices(){
        DataSource ds = Environment.getDataSource(appName);
        ServiceLocator.replaceService("Service", new Service(ds);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

We pass the DataSource into our services and they get passed through to our data access objects and stored as member variables, which should be the reference to the same DataSource object as we created in `Environment`.

```
public class Service {
    private ServiceDAO dao;

    public Service(DataSource ds){
        dao = new ServiceDAO(ds);
    }
}

public class ServiceDAO extends AbstractDAOService{
    public ServiceDAO(DataSource ds){
        super(ds);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractDAOService {
    private final DataSource datasource;

    public AbstractDAOService(DataSource ds){
        this.datasource = ds;
    }

    protected DataSource getDataSource(){
        return this.datasource;
    }

    protected int queryGetCount(ParameterQuery qry, String countColName){
        ConnectionQuery q = new ConnectionQuery(getDataSource(), qry);
        int retval = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = q.getResultSet();
            try {
                if(rs.next()){
                    retval = rs.getInt(countColName);
                }
            } finally {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
        q.close();
        return retval;
    }
}
```

The connection query object gets a connection from the data source and then makes a prepared statement and executes it to get the result set. The issue we are having is that there is a query that when run through this pipeline was taking a massive amount of time to complete. We have seen execution times ranging from 17 seconds to 90(!) seconds for a fairly simple query. When executed through SQL Server Management Studio the query runs in milliseconds. We added logging to determine exactly where in the code things were breaking down and the slowness was on `PreparedStatament.execute()`.

We noticed that if we replaced the `getDataSource()` method in `AbstractDAOSerice` to the following

```
protected DataSource getDataSource(){
    return Environment.getDataSource();
}
```

then the query executed with the same speed as when executed through SSMS. As far as we understand both of those solutions should be referencing the same object, so while we fixed the issue, we want to better understand *why* this was an issue to begin with and how our change fixed the issue. Any guidance from Java experts is greatly appreciated.

For reference we are on Java jdk1.8.0_144

Edit:

```
public class ConnectionQuery {
    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private final DataSource datasource;
    private ParameterQuery qry;

    public ConnectionQuery(DatasSource ds, ParamterQuery qry) {
        this.datasource = ds;
        this.qry = qry;
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Connection c = defineConnection(true);
            this.stmt = this.getQuery.makeStatement(c, false);
            this.stmt.execute();
            this.rs = this.stmt.getResultSet(); 
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            this.close();
            throw se;
        }
        return this.rs;
    }

    private Connection defineConnection(boolean readOnly) throws SQLException {
        if(this.con == null || this.con.isClosed()) {
            this.con = this.datasource.getConnection();
        }
        this.con.setReadOnly(readOnly);
        if(this.transactionIsolation != 777){
            this.con.setTransactionIsolation(this.transactionIsolation);
        }
        return this.con;
    }

    /**
     * close all parts of the connection, the RecordSet, the Statement, and the Connection
     */
    public void close() {
        if(this.rs != null) {
            try{
                this.rs.close();
                this.rs = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //warn
            }
        }
        if(this.stmt != null) {
            try{
                this.stmt.close();
                this.stmt = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //warn
            }
        }
        if(this.con != null) {
            try{
                this.con.close();
                this.con = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //warn
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The last part of the post refers to `return Environment.getDataSource();`, but that no argument method does not exist in the posted definition of `Environment`.  There's some missing context.  Also, what does `ConnectionQuery` do?  What code guarantees a `Connection` and `Statement` are properly closed?

Comment: @AndrewS I edited the post with the relevant information you requested. Also added the no param method for`getDataSource()`. Basically our service locator has the knowledge about the app name if we don't specify.

Comment: What does `defineConnection(true)` do?  is `c` the same as `con`?  Is `createDatasource()` guaranteed to occur only once?  How many concurrent requests does it take for the issue to occur?  How many concurrent connections will the database accept?

Comment: Also, add logging and/or profile the running app to determine where it's spending most of the time.

Comment: @AndrewS added the defineCollection method so you can see exactly what it's doing. As for logging we did that already as we were troubleshooting and the exact line that is taking a long time is `this.stmt.execute();` in the getResultSet() method. We broke it down line by line while debugging and every other line was taking a maximum of 1ms, mostly 0ms.

Comment: Also `createDatasource()` is guaranteed to only happen once, we can reproduce this issue with it being the only request happening on that specific database but other requests happening on our database server. The maximum connections we allow on the database side is unlimited but we limit it to 100 on the application side.

Comment: It does look like it should be the same DataSource.  Is the correct driver always being used? (Make sure there is only 1 version available to be loaded.)  Consider enabling trace logging for the driver.  Also, consider adding a max wait time on the DataSource just in case it takes too long waiting to borrow a Connection.  Perhaps combine `this.stmt.execute(); this.rs = this.stmt.getResultSet();` into `this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery();`.

Comment: @AndrewS Thank you for your comments and help on this issue. It turned out not to be a Java issue (which we're glad as it didn't make any sense to us that way) but ended up being a SQL issue we had not run into yet. I posted our findings in the answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up finding the solution to this issue, updating here in case anyone else runs into the same thing. The Java code change was a red herring, and had nothing to do with fixing the performance of the query.

What we had run into was [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/08/start-troubleshooting-parameter-sniffing-issues/).

A quick description of this issue is when SQL caches the execution plan for a query with a set of parameters that it works fine with, and then re-uses that execution plan with a different set of parameters that cause major performance issues. Brent Ozar goes into a lot more depth about this issue in the link above.

The reason we ran into this and that a code change actually did make it seem like it was working was because the query we were running was used to determine if certain objects in our system were in use by end users or not. If the first object we checked was not in use, then SQL would cache the execution plan for an object with no results and when used on and object with upwards of 14000 results(on a table with 108000 rows), the query took massively longer. We forced our query with the larger result set to run with the execution plan of the other query and reproduced this in SQL Server Management Studio to make sure there was no doubt in our finding.

The solution we are going forward with in our project is to revisit and optimize the query/table structure so that the execution plan is constant across different input parameters for this query and the execution time stays consistent as well.

Hope this information is helpful.

Comment: Nice to hear you found the problem! It would have actually been helpful if you had added (a pseudonymized version of) the original query to the question because that might have indicated this problem. When a query includes a parameter on a column that's highly selective (e.g. `active` column when only a fraction of data has the flag set), then it's actually a good idea _not_ to parameterize this condition; it's better to embed it into the query literal instead, to avoid this exact problem.